# find maximum occurrence in list and find pair in list

Tags: list, prolog

I'm a new in Haskell, but I wrote this solution in Prolog.

First one: I have to create function or a few functions that will find maximum occurrence in list. I would like to rewrite my Prolog function for that solution or if you know easier solution for that task, please write below.

Input: someFunc [1,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5]  Output: [3,4]

Input: someFunc [1,2,2,3,4,5]  Output: [2]

Prolog code:

```
listMax(L, M) :- listMax(L, [], [], M).

listMax([], Seen, MMax, Max) :- 
  (MMax == [] -> 
    Max = Seen
  ; listMax(MMax, [], [], Max)).

listMax([H|T], Seen, MMax, Max) :-
  (member(H, Seen) -> 
    listMax(T, Seen, [H|MMax], Max)
  ; listMax(T, [H|Seen], MMax, Max)).
```

Second one: I have to create fuction or a few functions that will find elements that are repeated many times as the pair in list.

Input: someFunc [2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5]   Output: [2,4]

Input: someFunc [1,1,2,2,2,3,3]   Output: [1,3]

Prolog code:

```
count([], _, 0).
count([H|T], H, R) :- count(T, H, RT), R is RT + 1.
count([H|T], X, R) :- H \= X, count(T, X, R).

add_if_count_is_one(H, T, H)  :- count(T, H, C), 0 is (C+1) mod 2.
add_if_count_is_one(H, T, []) :- count(T, H, C), 0 is C mod 2.
add_if_count_is_one(H, T, []) :- count(T, H, 0).

num_pairs([], []).
num_pairs([H|T], [H1|T1]) :- 
  delete(T, H, TT), 
  num_pairs(TT, T1), 
  add_if_count_is_one(H, T, H1).

listPair(M, RR):- 
  num_pairs(M, R), 
  delete(R,[],RR).
```

Comment: Are you asking someone to translate the code from Prolog to Haskell?  It would be better for you to do this yourself if you want to learn the language.  What have you attempted so far?  I know that several functions in `Data.List` would be useful for this task.

Comment: @bheklilr I know how to write this simple tasks with Java. And I know that would be better for me, but I have no spare time for study Haskell now. I have to write them up tomorrow.

Comment: Is that `Output: [1,3]` a typo?

Comment: @mbratch you don't know, what are you talking about. It's not a homework! I'm a Java developer, but sorry, I don't know Haskell and I need help urgently. And thanks a lot guys who made solution below.

Comment: @user3478707 I apologize for my mistaken perception. Usually (and often) someone will post a problem like this with the comment, "I have to create a function that..." which typically is a homework directive. We've even had people lie about trying to help their brother. I'm happy that you found your solution, and, again, apologize for any misperception.

Comment: @mbratch I'm not an native English speaker. But it's another question.   And you're right, It's not a good way for description problems. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Your English skills are good. It's really more the scenario. If a person is new to a language, offers no trial solutions in that language, and wants immediate help on two problems that are of an "exercise" nature, that almost always means a homework assignment. Your case is an exception. I'll ask to be sure next time. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second question can be solved by using some higher order functions in `Data.List`:

```
import Data.List

numPair :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
numPair xs = map head (filter ( even . length) (groupBy (==) xs))
```

Demo in ghci:

```
ghci > numPair [2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5]
[2,4]
ghci > numPair [1,1,2,2,2,3,3] 
[1,3]
```

You can use similar technique to solve your other question. Browse for functions in `Data.List` to get familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

This code implemented both those two functions:

```
import Data.List

-- Case 1
maxOccurrence :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
maxOccurrence = (map head) .  last . occurenceGroup

-- Case 2
maxOccurrenceNumber :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [(a, Int)]
maxOccurrenceNumber =
    (map (\l -> (head l, length l))) .
    last . occurenceGroup

-- Common function
occurenceGroup :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [[[a]]]
occurenceGroup =
        (groupBy (cmp (==))) . (sortBy (cmp compare)) .
        group . sort
    where
        cmp op = \a b -> op (length a) (length b)
```

That `occurenceGroup` will

1. sort and group the argument list by value of its elements, after this elements with same value will be in the same group
2. the sort and group the result from step one by length of its elements, after this elements with same length will be in the same group

After `occurenceGroup` rearranged the elements of its argument list, the implementations for both functions are trivial, they just take the last element of the result of `occurenceGroup`, and extract or compute the information they need.

---

Here is the full test program:

```
import Data.List

maxOccurrence :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
maxOccurrence = (map head) .  last . occurenceGroup

maxOccurrenceNumber :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [(a, Int)]
maxOccurrenceNumber =
    (map (\l -> (head l, length l))) .
    last . occurenceGroup

occurenceGroup :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [[[a]]]
occurenceGroup =
        (groupBy (cmp (==))) . (sortBy (cmp compare)) .
        group . sort
    where
        cmp op = \a b -> op (length a) (length b)

----

lst11, lst12, lst21, lst22 :: [Int]
lst11 = [1,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5]
lst12 = [1,2,2,3,4,5]
lst21 = [2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5]
lst22 = [1,1,2,2,2,3,3]

main = do
        putStrLn "Case 1:"
        output lst11
        output $ maxOccurrence lst11
        output lst12
        output $ maxOccurrence lst12
        putStrLn "Case 2:"
        output lst21
        output $ maxOccurrenceNumber lst21
        output lst22
        output $ maxOccurrenceNumber lst22
    where output lst = putStrLn $ show lst
```